# Invoke Flash Notice in Rails using [action].js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the rails flash notice to appear within my application by using JavaScript only. I have a form which leverages `remote: true` to make an AJAX request to the controller when submitting. The form looks like the example shown below:

```
  # app/views/_email_register.html.erb
  <%= simple_form_for :email, url: emails_path, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.input :address, as: :email, placeholder: 'user@domain.com', label: false %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit 'Subscribe', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The rails application was generated using rails-composer which also installed bootstrap css.

```
  # app/controllers/emails_controller.rb
  def create
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @email.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Email was successfully registerd' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

The controller then invokes the `create.js.erb` as part of the respond_to block.

```
  # app/views/emails/create.js.erb
  // flash to user it was successful
  $(".alert").html("Email was successfully registered");
```

The `_messages.html.erb` partial was automatically generated from rails-composer. Not sure if this partial can be invoked from the JavaScript

```
# app/views/layouts/_messages.html.erb
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %>">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any assistance on how I can get the flash notice to show up via JavaScript would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to re-render the partial which renders the flash messages in your js.erb

```
# app/views/emails/create.js.erb
$('.flash_wrapper').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/messages') %>");
```

In your controller set the flash

```
format.js { flash.now[:notice] = 'Email was successfully registered' }
```

This will show you flash

**NOTE:** `.flash_wrapper` is your wrapper where you are rendering the `_message` partial.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I have tried adding `$('#flash_notice').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/messages') %>");`, however the JS returned from the controller is the following `$('#flash_notice').html("");` It seem that it does not have a `flash` object to loop through.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I did and it's working well for me, please advise if this is proper:  `format.js { flash.now[:notice] = 'Email was successfully registered' }`